# I am trying to pick up sqlite using python and want to be able to get the number of rows that meet a certain criteria

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sqlite

I am loading an excel spreadsheet into an sql table and am able to see it (so that worked). I want to find out how many of the records meet a certain criteria. There are names in columns 1 and 2 and i'd ideally like to know how many occurrences there are of every pair in a list. I have tried to start simple and am able to access the excel data using pandas, create the table (df.to_sql - creates pairings) and select off all instances of a specific pair of names (results = engines.execute).

Please help me understand how to get access to the count of instances that are found using the results command. Here is the python - any help would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

file    = 'C:/Users/Pinev/Desktop/Pairings_List.xlsx'            # Excel input file
#output  = ''            # Excel output file

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo = False)

df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name ='Pairings_List')

print(df)

df.to_sql('pairings', engine, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)
print("5")
print(df)


results = engine.execute("Select * from pairings where Player1 = 'Bazoian, Scott'\
        AND Player2 = 'Brady, Brian'")

final = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = df.columns)

print("data Loaded")
print(final)
count = engine.execute("select count(*) from pairings")
print("count = ", count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably recommend this approach

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo = False)

base = automap_base()
base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

our_table = base.classes.pairings
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

s = Session()
results = s.query(our_table).filter_by(Player1='Bazoian, Scott', Player2='Brady, Brian').all()


s.commit()
```

commit will end your session, you can use filter_by as the "WHERE" in a string.
all() will print out all the results it will find, you can also use first() to only print the first result, and to count you can use count()

you can access it with simple attitude such as if you want to see the column Name

```
for player in results:
  print(player.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am just trying to get a count of the number of records that meet the criteria. I will probably have 20 - 30 names in any given week and need the count of pairings that have occurred in the past in order to create new ones that have been used the least.

Comment: @steve please read what I wrote you can use s.query(our_table).count() instead of all() to get the count